# how to clear the server drop down list of useless entries in Linqpad?

Tags: linqpad

In the LINQ to SQL connection window, the server drop down list now contains useless items from attempting to find the correct instance to connect to MS SQL server.
The only ones that work are (local) or localhost. Thinking that since .\SQLEXPRESS worked with SQL express version then .\MSSQLSERVER would work with the full version but I was mistaken! Anyway I digress, how do you clear these entries as pressing delete does not remove them? 
If anyone can also explain the other related part about  .\SQLEXPRESS and (local) working for express edition yet only (local) not .\mssqlserver (the default)  on the full versions (Enterprise or Standard?

Answer (score 0):

Delete `%appdata%\LINQPad\RecentServers.txt`

Which version of SQL Express do you have installed? The newest version is called LOCALDB and `.\SQLEXPRESS` will not work. Instead you must use `(localdb)\v11.0`